# Encounter error using DataExplorer.exe to connect to home grown DBX4 driver

Tags: delphi, dllimport

I have written my own DBX 4 in Delphi 2010 for Firebird database. The driver is a dynalink driver and it works fine with TSQLConnection.

Recently, I try to use the DataExplorer.exe released with Delphi 2010 and encounter error:

```
"Attempted to read or write protected memory.
 This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".
```

After trace the source code, I found the following export method may be the cause of the problem:

```
function DBXLoader_GetDriver(Count: TInt32; Names, Values: TWideStringArray;
  ErrorMessage: TDBXWideStringBuilder; out pDriver: TDBXDriverHandle):
  TDBXErrorCode; stdcall;
```

When debugging this method, the Names and Values parameter contain corrupted value. I don't know what cause the problem. Perhaps there is some memory manager problem with DataExplorer.exe (.net issue?)

After some trial and error, I attempt to change the method to as follow:

```
type
  TWideStringArray2 = array of PChar;

function DBXLoader_GetDriver(Count: TInt32; Names, Values: TWideStringArray2;
  ErrorMessage: TDBXWideStringBuilder; out pDriver: TDBXDriverHandle):
  TDBXErrorCode; stdcall;
```

This time, the error is gone and soon after it exit this method, the same error raise again

```
"Attempted to read or write protected memory.
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".
```

Do you have any ideas what could the the cause of the problem?

Comment: This is far less likely a .NET issue per se, than an issue in DataExplorer or your own code.

Comment: Some of the information in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765424/how-to-access-databases-from-within-delphi-xe-professional-ide) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some memory allocation problems. Are you using SimpleShareMem eventualy?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/SimpleShareMem_Sample - describes how to use it.

http://www.codexterity.com/memmgr.htm - also contains some insights on memory allocation but with older approachi using FastSharemem module.